# Writing frames appended in a list onto a video in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, frame

The code below reads a video and stores it frame by frame into a list. The reason for doing this is because I may want to have individual frames from the video for other purposes such as blurring or converting into a binary image. I then want to convert these processed frames into a video. My understanding of OpenCV lead me to write the code below but this is giving me a `Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'` error. Why is this the case?

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture("ThisVid.wmv")

#store every frame from video file 
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
frames = []
while success:
    frames.append(image)
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    count += 1

vidcap.release()

newframes = [] 

for i in range(0,len(frames),100):
    newframes.append(frames[i])
    
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("outputvideo.mp4",cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MP4V"),30,(512,512))
writer.write(cv2.resize(newframes,(512,512))) #write frame into output vid
writer.release()
```

Comment: for what line in your code is that error given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to give a suggestion:

```py
success = True
frames = []
while success:
```

Instead of writing like above, write like:

```py
frames = []
while vidcap.isOpened():
```

The above code make sense. If the video is opened then process its' frames.

My second suggestion is:

```py
frames.append(image)
success,image = vidcap.read()
count += 1
```

First check if the `frame` is returned, then append to the list.

```py
while vid_cap.isOpened():
    success, image = vid_cap.read()
    if success:
        frames.append(image)
        count += 1
```

You initialized `VideWriter` as:

```py
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("outputvideo.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MP4V"), 30, (512, 512))
```

There are two constraints:

---

1- Each frame must be (512, 512) size

2- And each frame must be rgb.

If you want to have grey-scale video, you need to set `isColor` variable to `False`

```py
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("outputvideo.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MP4V"), 30, (512, 512), isColor=False)
```

Since you want each frame size `(512, 512)` you could do: `img = cv2.resize(image, (512, 512))`

```py
while vid_cap.isOpened():
    success, image = vid_cap.read()
    if success:
        img = cv2.resize(image, (512, 512))
        frames.append(img)
        count += 1
    else:
        break
```

Now, `Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'` means `writer.write` first argument `image` should be a frame, but you gave a list input. Therefore:

1- Initialize the `VideoWriter` object

2- Instead of "MP4V" use "mp4v" otherwise you might get a warning

2- write frames using a `for-loop`

```py
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("outputvideo.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v"), 30, (512, 512))

for i in range(0, len(frames), 100):
    newframes.append(frames[i])
    writer.write(frames[i])

writer.release()
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

vid_cap = cv2.VideoCapture("result.mp4")

# store every frame from video file
success, image = vid_cap.read()
count = 0
frames = []

while vid_cap.isOpened():
    success, image = vid_cap.read()
    if success:
        img = cv2.resize(image, (512, 512))
        frames.append(img)
        count += 1
    else:
        break

vid_cap.release()

newframes = []

writer = cv2.VideoWriter("outputvideo.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v"), 30, (512, 512))

for i in range(0, len(frames), 100):
    newframes.append(frames[i])
    writer.write(frames[i])  # write frame into output vid

writer.release()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and a step by step reasoning to them. I can see the errors in my method and have rectified them accordingly. I was also just estimating the frame sizes but then found out I can get them by ```img.shape```. This has made it easily to write the frames.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes you could use `img.shape`. Let me give you a hint (maybe you have already know) if `img.shape` returns only two-variable, it means the image is grey-scale. i.e. `(512, 512)` is grey image, if `img.shape` returns three-variable i.e. `(512, 512, 3)` then the image is rgb.

Comment: `img.shape` returns height, and width respectively. Therefore when you are using, get height and width: `h, w = img.shape[:2]` then initialize `VideoWriter` as `writer = cv2.VideoWriter("outputvideo.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v"), 30, (w, h))` Don't forget to set `isScale=False` for grey-scale frames or images.

Answer (score 4):

`cv2.resize` expects *individual* images.  You are supplying a list of images which does not conform to the expected signature.  In addition, `cv2.VideoWriter.write` only writes one frame at a time and you are supplying a list of frames.  Therefore, in your loop with `newframes`, don't even use a new list.  Resize the frame in the loop, then write to disk.

```py
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("outputvideo.mp4",cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MP4V"),30,(512,512))
for i in range(0,len(frames),100):
    resiz = cv2.resize(frames[i], (512, 512))
    writer.write(resiz)
writer.release()
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvote - I wanted to make the answer short and succinct to solve the OP's problem.  Though the accepted answer has merit, I found it a bit too long to get to the issue. However, that style can be maintained if you first discuss what's wrong with the code, solve it *then* provide suggestions.